# vue project not working when change the base url in index.html file to my website url

Tags: vue.js, cpanel

This is my index.html file
when I change the base url to my website domain "https://new.weservio.com/"  this error appears
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` when I try to import vue according to this solution https://microeducate.tech/importing-a-package-in-es6-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-vue/ .other modules can't be resolved too.

```html
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <link href='images/logo.png' rel='icon' />
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport' />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com' rel='preconnect'>
    <link crossorigin href='https://fonts.gstatic.com' rel='preconnect'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;700;900&family=Tajawal:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap'
          rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href=' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.0-beta.14/vue.esm-browser.js' >
    <title></title>
    <!--
    EDIT THE FOLLOWING CODE INSIDE THE BASE TAG
    'http://localhost:3000/' ==> 'REPLACE IT WITH YOUR BASE URL'
    -->
    <base href='https://new.weservio.com/'>
   
</head>
<body class='rtl:font-tajawal font-poppins overflow-x-hidden'>
<div id='app'></div>
```

**notice**: when I leave the url as "http://localhost:3000/" and run the project locally with `npm run dev` .The website is working fine.

**notice**: This site was working correctly before on same domain url ,but I was tring to use ftp-simple extention on vs code to load automaticllay after save to server from my working directory .then the website is not working anymore .I don't know if this related.

Comment: I think you have to run  `npm run build` and upload the dist folder to your hosting server, when npm run that command Vue will be compressed in a .js file, could you try again?

Comment: I already did that

Comment: I also tried to remove node modules and run npm install from server but this error appears node: error while loading shared libraries: libbrotlidec.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you try installing these libraries on your server, I hope is an Ubuntu server, right? `sudo apt-get install libaio1 libaio-dev`